# How to check the request body parameters type validation in akka http micro-services?

Tags: scala, akka, microservices, akka-http

my Object is

```
case class  Request(id:Int,name:String,phone:String)
```

my request in postman is

```
{
    "id":   "1205", **here i have changed the request body parameter type Int to String**
    "name":     "sekhar",
    "phone":"1234567890"

}
```

how can I check the request parameter is valid or invalid when my request body field is the wrong data type

I have used

```
implicit def myRejectionHandler = RejectionHandler.newBuilder()
    .handle {
      case MissingQueryParamRejection(param) =>
        println(" Test1  ")
        val errorResponse = ErrorResponse(BadRequest.intValue, "Missing Parameter", s"The required $param was not found.")
        var json:JsValue=Json.toJson(errorResponse)
        complete(HttpResponse(BadRequest, entity = HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`application/json`, json.toString())))
    }
    .handle { case MissingFormFieldRejection(msg) =>
      println(" Test2  ")
      complete(BadRequest, msg)
    }
    .handle { case MalformedQueryParamRejection(msg,error,cause) =>
      println(" Test3  ")
      complete(BadRequest, msg)
    }
    .handleAll[MethodRejection] { methodRejections =>
    val names = methodRejections.map(_.supported.name)
     println(" Test4  ")
    complete((MethodNotAllowed, s"Can't do that! Supported: ${names mkString " or "}!"))
    }
    .handleNotFound { complete((NotFound, "Not here!")) }
    .result()

val routes: Route = handleRejections(myRejectionHandler) {
    //Routes 
  }
 Http().bindAndHandle(routes, "localhost", 8090)
```

it's, again and again, takes only handleAll[MethodRejection] when being changed the query params(for the false parameter too) on that time too.

Comment: How are you unmarshalling the json? are you sure the exception you are trying to catch is being thrown?

Comment: am not sure unmarshalling needed or not, I have used unmarshalling after successful request  when am calling the service directly server rejected my request,

 (post & entity(as[Request])) { edit =>

          //my code
        } // directly rejected by server
and directly jumped into the .handleAll[MethodRejection]

Comment: I mean, where are you throwing the `MissingQueryParamRejection`, have you got a snippet?

Comment: when am calling the postman request it's directly rejected, I think this query parameter rejection in scala

Comment: Oh, I see. the `MalformedQueryParamRejection` is thrown by Akka when there are problems with the query parameters. You are making the request sending a Json object, its not the same thing. That is why I was asking (and asking again): How are you un-marshalling the Json into case class? Are you using Spray Json?

Comment: yes, am using Spray Json 
import akka.http.scaladsl.marshallers.sprayjson.SprayJsonSupport._

libraryDependencies is
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-spray-json" % "10.0.10",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Spray Json, then you might have created a format for your case class, it should look like this:

Assuming:

```
case class Request(id:Int, name:String, phone:String)
```

You should have a trait like:

```
import spray.json._

trait RequestJsonSupport extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val requestFormat = jsonFormat3(Request.apply)
}
```

And then extend it on your route class:

```
class MyRouteClass(...) extends RequestJsonSupport {...}
```

That way your Akka Http instance knows how to parse a Json input and convert it into your case class. Then you can worry about missing fields and such. Spray will take care of this.

For example, if you sent this:

```
{
    "id":   "1205",
    "name":     "sekhar",
    "phone":"1234567890"
}
```

Spray will throw an:

```
The request content was malformed:
Expected Int as JsNumber, but got "1205"
```

Check out Spray Json repo [here](https://github.com/spray/spray-json#providing-jsonformats-for-case-classes).

Comment: I have used trait too,


trait RequestJsonSupport extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val RequestFormat = jsonFormat3(Request.apply)
  
  implicit val requestWrites = new Writes[Request] {
    def writes(json_write: Request): JsValue = {
      Json.obj(
        "id" -> json_write.id,
        "name" -> json_write.name,
        "phone" -> json_write.phone
      )
    }
  }
}

my code works fine in all cases, but I need to handle the if request parameter is a different datatype(if "id" is Int datatype if my request is another datatype on that time also I need to handle)

Comment: Check here: https://github.com/spray/spray-json/blob/7c332d1d67b581e23163a90714fa15615996a7b8/src/main/scala/spray/json/package.scala#L23
That is the exception Spray will throw when you have the wrong field, use that on the Akka's Exception handler.